# The tiles of the basemap cannot be downloaded due to a security issue while the map is not secured

Tags: tiles, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

> The tiles of the basemap cannot be downloaded due to a security issue
>   while the map is not secured.

Despite the fact that the basemap was shared with everybody on the ArcGIS Online (AGOL), the ArcGIS collector is unable to download the map to be used offline and displays the following message “the map failed to download with the message: Unauthorized access to a secure service“. It seems that there is a security issue that prevents the tiles to be downloaded to the device. What might be the source of it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could ask ESRI? There isn't much to go on here, and its obviously hard to debug when you don't have logs or source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the web map with everyone leads to this issue if you changed the shared to be organization instead of everyone the tiles then can be downloaded, this is a really strange behavior which I cannot understand.